# Cordova Client Phonegap Upgrade

Tags: cordova, client

I am using cordova client for my phonegap project.I got a question when i type 
cordova create name namespace its all working fine.I want to add platforms and i got an error, when i do this for android. e.g.

`Error : An error occurred during creation of android sub-project. cp /usr/local/lib/node_module/cordova/lib/android/framework/cordova-2.2.0.jar ..`

i copied it manually since i didn't figure out how to slove it.

Can someone help me to explain it and how i can update it to 2.7 ? i did npm install cordova.. he took all the new sources but when i type codorva create xxx and add a plattform i got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `npm update cordova` command? It will update to the latest cordova version (2.7.2 at the moment)

Comment: yes that did it thank you :) and the chown -R username /cordova-dir was the problem